# Count items in order next 12 months

Tags: sql-server

I need to get Quantity of items in orders the next 12 months, like this:

| ItemNumber | August 22 | September 22 | October 22 | November 22 | etc.. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| item1 | 10 | 13 | 12 | 130 | .. |
| item2 | 20 | 23 | 22 | 230 | .. |

I can do like this for one month and repeat, but think there is a better way to do it.

```
 SELECT I.ItemNumber, ThisMonth.Quantity AS This, NextMonth.Quantity AS Next * 
 FROM Items I
 LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT Quantity,Itemno 
    FROM [Orders] 
    WHERE MONTH([Shipment Date]) = MONTH(GETDATE()) AND YEAR([Shipment Date]) = YEAR(GETDATE())
 ) AS ThisMonth ON ThisMonth.Itemno = I.Itemnumber
 LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT Quantity,Itemno  
    FROM [Orders] 
    WHERE MONTH([Shipment Date]) = MONTH(DATEADD(month,+1,GETDATE())) AND YEAR([Shipment Date]) = YEAR(GETDATE())
 ) AS NextMonth ON NextMonth.Itemno = I.Itemnumber
```

Can you help? :)

*UPDATED WITH MY TABLE DATA BELOW*

**ITEMS:**

| ItemNumber |
| --- |
| item1 |
| item2 |

**ORDERS:**

| ItemNo | Shipment Date | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| item1 | 2022-08-02 | 10 |
| item1 | 2022-09-02 | 13 |
| item1 | 2022-10-02 | 12 |
| item1 | 2022-11-02 | 130 |
| item2 | 2022-08-02 | 20 |
| item3 | 2022-09-02 | 23 |
| item4 | 2022-10-02 | 22 |
| item5 | 2022-11-02 | 230 |

Comment: You need to show us some sample data from the base table and the corresponding expected result. Please post as formatted text and not as image

Comment: Done.. my post are updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible option, using the `PIVOT` relational operator:

Sample data:

```
SELECT *
INTO Items
FROM (VALUES
   ('item1', CONVERT(date, '20220802'), 10),
   ('item1', CONVERT(date, '20220902'), 13),
   ('item1', CONVERT(date, '20221002'), 12),
   ('item1', CONVERT(date, '20221102'), 130),
   ('item2', CONVERT(date, '20220802'), 20),
   ('item3', CONVERT(date, '20220902'), 23),
   ('item4', CONVERT(date, '20221002'), 22),
   ('item5', CONVERT(date, '20221102'), 230)
) t (ItemNo, ShipmentDate, Quantity)
```

Statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT ItemNo, Quantity, DATEDIFF(month, EOMONTH(GETDATE()), EOMONTH(ShipmentDate)) AS NextMonth
   FROM Items
) t
PIVOT (
   SUM(Quantity)
   FOR NextMonth IN ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11])
) p
```

Result:

| ItemNo | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| item1 | 10 | 13 | 12 | 130 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| item2 | 20 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| item3 |  | 23 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| item4 |  |  | 22 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| item5 |  |  |  | 230 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Answer (score 2):

You haven't supplied sample data, but it looks like you need conditional aggregation (aka a pivot). It's generally easier, if a bit more verbose, to do this with `SUM(CASE` rather than using the `PIVOT` operator.

```sql
SELECT
  i.ItemNumber,
  SUM(CASE WHEN EOMONTH(i.[Shipment Date]) = EOMONTH(GETDATE()) THEN i.Quantity END) AS CurrentMonth,
  SUM(CASE WHEN EOMONTH(i.[Shipment Date]) = EOMONTH(GETDATE(), 1) THEN i.Quantity END) AS Month1,
  SUM(CASE WHEN EOMONTH(i.[Shipment Date]) = EOMONTH(GETDATE(), 2) THEN i.Quantity END) AS Month2,
  SUM(CASE WHEN EOMONTH(i.[Shipment Date]) = EOMONTH(GETDATE(), 3) THEN i.Quantity END) AS Month3,
  SUM(CASE WHEN EOMONTH(i.[Shipment Date]) = EOMONTH(GETDATE(), 4) THEN i.Quantity END) AS Month4,
  SUM(CASE WHEN EOMONTH(i.[Shipment Date]) = EOMONTH(GETDATE(), 5) THEN i.Quantity END) AS Month5,
  SUM(CASE WHEN EOMONTH(i.[Shipment Date]) = EOMONTH(GETDATE(), 6) THEN i.Quantity END) AS Month6,
  SUM(CASE WHEN EOMONTH(i.[Shipment Date]) = EOMONTH(GETDATE(), 7) THEN i.Quantity END) AS Month7,
  SUM(CASE WHEN EOMONTH(i.[Shipment Date]) = EOMONTH(GETDATE(), 8) THEN i.Quantity END) AS Month8,
  SUM(CASE WHEN EOMONTH(i.[Shipment Date]) = EOMONTH(GETDATE(), 9) THEN i.Quantity END) AS Month9,
  SUM(CASE WHEN EOMONTH(i.[Shipment Date]) = EOMONTH(GETDATE(), 10) THEN i.Quantity END) AS Month10,
  SUM(CASE WHEN EOMONTH(i.[Shipment Date]) = EOMONTH(GETDATE(), 11) THEN i.Quantity END) AS Month11,
FROM Items i
GROUP BY
  i.ItemNumber;
```